# Parse XML TO JAVA POJO in efficient way

Tags: java, xml, parsing, pojo

How to parse and create java pojo for below xml in an efficient way?  Kindly suggest any efficient parser.

XML format is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CCMainRootTag ID="12">
  <Header TableName="TableName"    TableVersion="12" TableID="12" CreatedDate="2013-02-09T15:35:33" CreatedByUserName="ABC" CreatedBySystem="ABC" />
  <ClassPrimary ID="12" Code="Y" DescriptionDK="DK language " DescriptionUK="" DefDK="" DefUK="" IFDGUID="">
    <ObjectClass ID="12" Code="YA" DescriptionDK="DK Language" DescriptionUK="" DefDK=""     DefUK="" IFDGUID="">
      <Synonym>
        <Concept Description="Description" Language="DK" />
        <Concept Description="" Language="UK" />
        <Concept Description="Description" Language="DK" />
        <Concept Description="" Language="UK" />
        <Concept Description="Description" Language="DK" />
        <Concept Description="" Language="UK" />
        <Concept Description="Description" Language="DK" />
        <Concept Description="" Language="UK" />
      </Synonym>
    </ObjectClass>
    <ObjectClass ID="12" Code="YB" DescriptionDK="DK Language" DescriptionUK="" DefDK="" DefUK="" IFDGUID=""> </ObjectClass>
    <ObjectClass ID="12" Code="YC" DescriptionDK="DK Language" DescriptionUK="" DefDK="" DefUK="" IFDGUID=""> </ObjectClass>
    <ObjectClass ID="12" Code="YD" DescriptionDK="DK language" DescriptionUK="" DefDK="" DefUK="" IFDGUID=""> </ObjectClass>
  </ClassPrimary>
</CCMainRootTag>
```

I already use this[Link](http://code.google.com/p/pojoxml/) but it have slow performance and having problem did't valid pojo.

I want to parser which provide me direct java pojo in a efficient way.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) to convert XML into Java POJOs. But before you finalize the solution [check this site](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/jaxb-sax-dom-performance.html) for performance comparison.

Comment: HI CuriousMind,
But in my case the xml attributes will be class variables.

See this for example.
TableName="TableName"    TableVersion="12" TableID="12" CreatedDate="2013-02-09T15:35:33" CreatedByUserName="ABC" CreatedBySystem="ABC" />

How can i define xml pojo for this type of structure.?

Comment: JAXB provides you annotations to bind attributes to Class variables. Check the JAXB documentation site for more details.

Answer (score 8):

For those looking for JAXB code to convert xml to java object:

```
//Convert xml to String first
Element partyLoaderRequest; // your xml data
String xmlString = new XMLOutputter().outputString(partyLoaderRequest);   
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes());
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = docBuilder.parse(is);
org.w3c.dom.Element varElement = document.getDocumentElement();
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<Person> loader = unmarshaller.unmarshal(varElement, Person.class);
Person inputFromXml = loader.getValue();
```

whereas Person has proper XML annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
public class CimbWlAdminUserAmendInput {
    @XmlElement(name="companyName",required=true,nillable=false) 
    private String companyName;
    ...
    //setters getters
    @XmlTransient
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialization and Deserialization can be handle by JacksonXmlModule.

```
// Item.class - use lombok or create g/setters
@JsonPropertyOrder({"name", "description", "note"})
public class Item { 
   private String name;
   private String description;
   private String note;
}


// Test.class
package hello.service;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.JacksonXmlModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import hello.entity.Item;
import org.junit.Before;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class NameServiceImplTest {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        JacksonXmlModule xmlModule = new JacksonXmlModule();
        xmlModule.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
        this.objectMapper = new XmlMapper(xmlModule);
        this.objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    }

    @Test
    public void serializeTest() {

        // Wrapper
        @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "names")
        class Names {
            public List<Item> item = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setName("Vladimir");
        item.setDescription("Desc");
        item.setNote("Note");

        Item item2 = new Item();
        item2.setName("Iva");
        item2.setDescription("Desc2");
        item2.setNote("Note2");

        Names names = new Names();
        names.item.add(item);
        names.item.add(item2);

        try {
            String xml = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(names);
            assertNotNull(xml);
            System.out.println(xml);
        } catch (Exception e) { // IOException
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            fail();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void deserializeTest() {
        String xml = "<names>" +
                "<item><name>name</name><description>desc</description><note>note</note></item>" +
                "<item><name>name</name><description>desc</description><note>note</note></item>" +
                "</names>";

        try {
            List<Item> names = objectMapper.readValue(xml, new TypeReference<List<Item>>() {});
            names.forEach(item -> {

                assertEquals("name", item.getName());
                assertEquals("desc", item.getDescription());
                assertEquals("note", item.getNote());

            } );
        } catch (Exception e) { // IOException

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class XmlConvertUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResultDataSet resultDataSet = new ResultDataSet(new DtInformation("0", "Success"), new DtData("980000001"));
        //Method which uses JAXB to convert object to XML
        System.out.println(JaxbObjToXML(resultDataSet));
    }

    public static Object JaxbXmlToObj(String xmlString, Object obj) {

        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            Object resultDataSet = (Object) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString));

            //System.out.println(resultDataSet);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public static String JaxbObjToXML(Object object) {
        String xmlContent = null;
        try {
            //Create JAXB Context
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());

            //Create Marshaller
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            //Required formatting??
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

            //Print XML String to Console
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            //Write XML to StringWriter
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(object, sw);

            //Verify XML Content
            xmlContent = sw.toString();
            //System.out.println(xmlContent);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xmlContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. Can you also explain it a bit?