# How to refer a drawable shape and change its color from java file?

Tags: java, android

I have a shape in circle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <size
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="200dp" />
    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
</shape>
```

How do i refer it from java and change its color ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14789329/7591918 - As the linked answer states, you can use JAXB. Just make a class containing all the necessary data, convert your XML file to a POJO and change it's color as a value from within your app.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating shape in java without xml.

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable=new GradientDrawable();
gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
gradientDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
gradientDrawable.setSize(200,200);
gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(100);
```

Or you can inflate the existing shape from xml and change it's properties like this,

```
GradientDrawable shapeDrawable= (GradientDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.shape);
shapeDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
imageView.setImageDrawable(shapeDrawable);
```

Comment: hi, i dont wanna draw a new shape. i just need to refer that is already in the xml file

Comment: no, i used shapeDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary)); though becuase getcolor is deprecated

Comment: what output you are getting,when using the above code.

Comment: Its running, no color change. iv put this shape as a background of a textview. So the third line of ur code is not needed right ?